# How to import and export All algolia settings using scripts

Tags: meteor, algolia

I have an issue with algolia settings. I can not import or export settings from aloglia. There is no settings or tools to do this.

I want to do it using my own script. How is it possible? Is there any alternative to do this or i have to create a script for that?

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [Algolia CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@algolia/cli) tool!

- Installation: `npm install -g @algolia/cli`
- Docs: https://github.com/algolia/algolia-cli

---

While you can still certainly write your own scripts to import/export settings or records, with the Algolia CLI tool you can also do it at the command line like so:

```
$ algolia getsettings -a <algoliaAppId> -k <algoliaApiKey> -n <algoliaIndexName>
```

and

```
$ algolia setsettings -a <algoliaAppId> -k <algoliaApiKey> -n <algoliaIndexName> -s <sourceFilepath> -p <setSettingsParams>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to export/import index settings is to use Algolia's REST API clients and the `{get,set}_settings` methods.

Building a small script wrapping those 2 commands is pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

Sepehr's answer is really helpful in pointing out how to achieve it with Algolia CLI. A time saver!

Here is the exact command you need to execute in your command line in order to:

**Export index**:

```
algolia export -a <algoliaAppId> -k <algoliaApiKey> -n <algoliaIndexName> -o <outputPath> -p <algoliaParams>
```

Example: `algolia export -a EXAMPLE_APP_ID -k EXAMPLE_API_KEY -n EXAMPLE_INDEX_NAME -o ~/Desktop/example_output_folder/ -p '{"filters":["category:book"]}'`

Params -p argument is optional and you can skip it.

**Import index**:

```
algolia import -s <sourceFilepath> -a <algoliaAppId> -k <algoliaApiKey> -n <algoliaIndexName> -b <batchSize> -t <transformationFilepath> -m <maxconcurrency> -p <csvToJsonParams>
```

Example: `algolia import -s ~/Desktop/example_source_directory/ -a EXAMPLE_APP_ID -k EXAMPLE_API_KEY -n EXAMPLE_INDEX_NAME -b 5000 -t ~/Desktop/example_transformations.js -m 4 -p '{"delimiter":[":"]}'`

More at https://github.com/algolia/algolia-cli#examples